# can you lock screen programmatically in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to lock the screen from your app in wp7?

Comment: it is possible but i dont know how it is made.
here is the sample app.
[Lock Screen](http://www.windowsphone.com/tr-tr/store/app/lock-screen/f93c89f3-2136-4640-8f58-ecf86aba05b9)

Answer (score 5):

No, Windows Phone 7 API doesn't have such an option for now.

Comment: Do you have a link to support that?

Comment: No explicit link out there. It just isn't part of the APIs or platform. +1

Comment: Agreed with Jeff, it's just not supported.

Comment: In general they don't want you to override or change global system settings.  Since the screen timeout is a global system setting, it follows that they wouldn't want you to do that.  At least, that's my thinking.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: I agree with your assessment, and I really hope they keep it that way. Any app that took the liberty of locking my phone's screen would be uninstalled as soon as I got the screen unlocked again.