# calling Windows Phone 7 lockscreen programmatically

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-7, lockscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can you lock screen programmatically in wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857757/can-you-lock-screen-programmatically-in-wp7)

I'd like to write an application for locking the screen (let's say, to reduce wear on the hardware lock button - locking the phone by pressing on the screen) - how could I accomplish this?

(VB.NET or C# prefered)

BTW: I'm aware this was asked here before - but the other guy asking this had the intention to run his code in the background while phone was locked. I really want to lock the phone using code!! :)

Comment: No it isn't. The other question is misnamed and should probably read "how can I run my app in the background while my phone is locked"..

Comment: Ah, my fault. Seems its not possible or at least not supported. Question answered. :)