# Can we get the time specified in the phone setting screen of windows phone 7 for locking the screen?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to get the time specified by the user in the phone settings screen for locking the screen. Can we get that time in our application. It's important. Please help.

Comment: I'm very sorry if this is off-topic, but could you please rephrase your question in normal English using punctuation. Also your question is not clear at all (to me at least)!

Answer (score 1):

As developers we do not have access to this setting. There is no way for us to get the time they have set for the phone to lock.

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857757/can-you-lock-screen-programmatically-in-wp7) for more info.

**Update:** If you need to know when the phone get's locked (or becomes idle) check out this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941090%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) on msdn.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. This value is not available to the application.

Perhaps you could explain to us why you need it and we might be able to help you.