# It is possible to switch windows phone 7 device to lock screen mode from my application?

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can you lock screen programmatically in wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857757/can-you-lock-screen-programmatically-in-wp7)

It is possible to switch windows phone 7 device to lock screen mode from my application? I know about ApplicationIdleDetectionMode, but I don't need to have working application in background mode.

Answer (score 1):

No. Windows Phone 7 API do not have such an option. See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4857764/925202).